# Unwanted Json appers in html

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a problem in my code which I can not see where the problem comes.
When I get the JSON data in JS, shows the structure of the array on the Web page, as shown in the picture below.
[image]

This is an excerpt from my JS code

```
var proj = document.getElementById('ProjetosSelect').value;
$.ajax({
    url: 'CRM files/TSread.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: ({ProjetosSelect: proj}),
    dataType: "json",
    complete:function(data) 
    {
        ProjetoHoras = data.responseJSON.total;
        ProjetoGastas = data.responseJSON.gastas;
        var PorGastar = ProjetoHoras - ProjetoGastas;
        $('#graficos').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column',
                margin: 75,
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 10,
                    beta: 25,
                    depth: 70
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Horas Contratadas'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    depth: 25
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: 
                 ['Horas Totails','Horas Gastas','Horas por Gastar']   

            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Horas',
                data: [ProjetoHoras, ProjetoGastas, PorGastar]
            }]
        });

    }

});
```

and this is an excerpt from my PHP code

```
$output = array('total'=>(float)$BHoras[1], 'gastas'=>(float)$BHoras[2]);
echo json_encode($output);
```

it is possible to eliminate " {"total":0,"gastas":0} " from web page?

Comment: don't echo it ... `echo json_encode($output);`

Comment: if i delete echo, how i pass the information to JS?

Comment: In that case - if the PHP you posted is part of `TSread.php`, and you only ever access `TSread.php` using $.ajax then the only thing that is putting that string in your webpage is your javascript ...

Comment: already edited my post, now is the function of the complete JS

Comment: Something else is going in your JavaScript that is not included in your snippet. Nothing in the code you have posted will output the raw JSON response. Are you using JSON.stringify() anywhere at all?

Comment: that snippet its all my JS code for that page :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content is echoed for both the web page and the ajax.

Each of them should have a distinct url.
The PHP page which echos the array JSON should be in a different url from the webpage itself.

Otherwise, you can use a parameter to distinguish them like so:

In Javascript add:

```
data: ({ProjetosSelect: proj,action:'json'}),
```

In php:

```
    if( ! empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action] == 'json'){
      $output = array('total'=>(float)$BHoras[1], 'gastas'=>  (float)$BHoras[2]);
      echo json_encode($output);
   }
```